# Entity Framework Core - Relationship between owned child and another chained owned child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am stuck with Problem, that I am trying to solve the right way.

I have multiple one-to-many 'owning' relationships. But I have a duplicate relationship between two children A should have List of Es and chained child D should point to one D from this List. I cannot set one class to be owned by 2 entities and with just 'having' relationship I am not able to save the whole structure at once. Example of how my code structure looks.

```
public class A //Main structure class
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("FK_A_ID")]
   public List<B> Bs {get; set;} //Set as OwnsMany

   [ForeignKey("FK_A_ID")]
   public List<D> Ds {get; set;} //Set as OwnsMany
}

public class B
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("FK_B_ID")]
   public List<C> Cs {get; set;} //Set as OwnsMany

   public int FK_A_ID { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("FK_C_ID")]
   public List<D> Ds {get; set;} //Set as OwnsMany

   public int FK_B_ID { get; set; }
}

public class D //referencing to one
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("FK_D_ID")]
   public List<E> Fs {get; set;} //Set as OwnsMany

   public int FK_C_ID { get; set; }
}

// Child that I need to have in both one A (A OwnsMany E) and multiple Ds (D has/owns one E respectively E has/owns multiple Ds)
public class E 
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("FK_E_ID")]
   public List<F> Fs {get; set;} // Trying to set as OwnsMany/HasMany

   public int FK_A_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is, that I do not know how to best specify this relationship for EF Core right.

I was trying Owning the relationship A-E and having the relationship D-E or E-D which throws error on migration. With having relationship A-E, saving throws foreign key violation, as FK is 0, because A was not saved yet and has no ID.
I would like to save it all as one (if possible) and load it all as one, as I have Angular front end expecting it and sending it back edited.

I hope someone has already solved a scenario like this, but I can not find anything for a case like this in the documentation.

Comment: `.OwnsMany` or `.HasMany`? Which database provider are you using?

Comment: Npgsql for Postgres. I specified OwnsMany and HasMany here in example in code comments next to collections, as copying and rewriting FluentAPI here would be more chaotic. Best option for me would be OwnsMany between both A-E and E-D. But then EF throws error, that it cannot resolve relationship between E-D

Comment: Sounds like a diamond-shaped relationship where one entity has two parents who in turn have a common ancestor. Ignoring EF and talking about SQL, this could be modeled by making FK_A_ID part of a composite primary key in the whole chain of relations, instead of "just" a foreign key. This way the relationship would enforce common ancestry. Otherwise, the foreign keys within `E` could point to an `A_1` and to a `D` which in turn has a parent chain ending at `A_2`. As long as the technical possibility of different ancestors exist, EF has no chance of doing it "right".

Comment: I feel like you wouldn't really need classes `A` to `E` in order to present the basic structure of your problem... maybe you can reduce your example to 3 classes (C is child of A and B; B is child of A)? Unless you already know how to make such a relation work with 3 - then go ahead and explain what makes your case more complicated.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for your comment. Sorry for my late answer. It is complicated for the reason, that I need A to have a list of possibilities - E and one D is using one of the possibilities. For example (I am doing something else): There is a system (A) with multiple access privileges (F) and multiple categorizations and Users (A-C) and they have some time-limited access 'blocks' with one privilege each (D-E). I just forged this concept, so the relations could be easier to understand. In my real case it is something like list of variables (Es) that can and don't need to have changes (Ds).

Comment: @grek40 So practically `Es` can be referenced multiple times and they need to be listed explicitly, as they are created and then referenced multiple times.

Comment: Typically, in a relational structure, a child references its parent, not the other way round... so, if you have a list of `E` associated with some parent `D` and some parent `A`, then `E` needs to know about its various **optional and/or required parents**. The parents know nothing about their childs (until EF starts converting from the relational database structure to the object model). In your description, the structure of each involved entity is not entirely clear to me. For example you write "A should have List of Es" and then `class A` has `List<D>` in the code.

Comment: Ok, try to think about it this way. `List<E> of A` is list of all entities. that could be changed. `A-D` is nesting of multiple objects in some state structure. In this structure `D` is the final endpoint which holds a change of value of selected `E` entity in some state. Same `E` can be changed in multiple states. It is practically customizable statemachine. Like when you have story with multiple options, which will point you to different story branches with change of Money, Morale etc.. In this case you can customize this variables Money etc. `Es` and their changes in different options `D-E`

Comment: ... In this case it seems like looking into all `Ds` via whole structure and getting `Es`, but there are `Es` like Name in example, that you do not want to change in whole Story `A`. I think this example is much nearer to what I am trying to achieve. There is one way how I can achieve it by giving HasOne relationship to `D-E` (if this will work) and detaching `Ds` in all `Cs` before first save. Saving it like that and then reattaching them and saving it one more time, as `Es` will already exist. But I do not know if this is right way to do it.

Comment: I'll try to repeat what I understood here. You have a story `A` with a list of entities `E` that appear at some point in the story. The story `progresses` and during that story progressing, there are potential `state changes`, where the `current value` of some entity `E` changes in comparison to its `previous value`. There is an `initial value` and the `history of values` from the `initial value` to the `current value` with all `intermediate values` is available.

Comment: If that's correct, can you edit your question with the story example and explain clearly, how your data model represents `initial value`, `history of values` and `current value`?

Comment: You are more or less right. I think for example it is what I am looking for. I will try to update it to be more Example oriented.

Comment: I edited to structure and found another Problem. At this point, I hope it will be more clear. It somehow fits into some kind of Interactive story that corresponds with the relationships of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `OwnsMany` is a special kind of relationship that's not suitable as soon as you have multiple entities with navigation properties to the same target. In such cases, you should use `HasMany` relationship.

When you have multiple references to the same entity (like `TransitionOptions` that belongs to some `CurrentStep` and points to some `NextStep`), use FluentApi or annotate with `InversePropertyAnnotation`, not with `ForeignKeyAnnotation`.

Generally, I'd advise you to use more fluent api configuration and less annotation based configuration - it's easier to maintain.

Here is some sample code based on your question.

Model classes

```
public class Story
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Step>? Steps { get; set; }

    public List<Variable>? Variables { get; set; }
}

public class Variable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StoryId { get; set; }

    public string? Value { get; set; }

    public Story? Story { get; set; }

    public List<Change>? Changes { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StoryId { get; set; }

    public Story? Story { get; set; }

    public List<TransitionOption>? TransitionOptions { get; set; }
}

public class TransitionOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StepId { get; set; }

    public int? NextStepId { get; set; }

    public Step? CurrentStep { get; set; }

    public Step? NextStep { get; set; }
    
    public List<Change>? Changes { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    // If combination of TransitionOptionId and VariableId is unique,
    // you can use them as composite key instead
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TransitionOptionId { get; set; }

    public int VariableId { get; set; }

    public Variable? Variable { get; set; }

    public TransitionOption? TransitionOption { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Configuration classes

```
internal class StoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Story>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Story> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Variables)
            .WithOne(x => x.Story)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.Steps)
            .WithOne(x => x.Story)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
internal class VariableConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Variable>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Variable> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Changes)
            .WithOne(x => x.Variable)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.VariableId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
internal class StepConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Step>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Step> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.TransitionOptions)
            .WithOne(x => x.CurrentStep)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StepId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        // No navigation property in Step for TransitionOptions pointing
        // to this as NextStep.
        // It would also be possible to define such a property and mention it
        // in HasMany
        builder.HasMany<TransitionOption>()
            .WithOne(x => x.NextStep)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.NextStepId)
            // If next step is deleted, only disconnect referencing TransitionOptions
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
internal class TransitionOptionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TransitionOption>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TransitionOption> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Changes)
            .WithOne(x => x.TransitionOption)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TransitionOptionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Apply the configurations within the `OnModelCreating` method.

Sample method to create a whole story structure with 1 `SaveChanges`

```
public async Task InitDb(MyDatabase db)
{
    var variable1 = new Variable
    {
        Value = "1st Value"
    };
    db.Stories?.Add(new Story
    {
        Variables = new List<Variable>
        {
            variable1
        },
        Steps = new List<Step>
        {
            new Step
            {
                TransitionOptions = new List<TransitionOption>
                {
                    new TransitionOption
                    {
                        Changes = new List<Change>
                        {
                            new Change
                            {
                                Variable=variable1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Hope this example shows everything you need for your described structure.

Comment: Thank you very much :) You put a lot of time into that and made it a lot better for me to understand. I will try it soon and I will get back to you if something comes up.

Comment: @lagugula if the answer helped you solving the problem, consider accepting it. Otherwise feel free to specify the remaining problems, maybe I can address them.

Comment: Sadly,  I was not able to fully get to that yet because of my limited time. I will surely look into it this weekend.

Comment: Seems it will take much longer to make it all better in my current solution as it is not 100% the same as my example scenario and I need to make a lot of changes in Angular to fit. For now, this is the best solution and seems very good. Thank you very much. I will accept this as a solution and I will write a comment if some problem comes up.